# How to wait for Promise.all() to complete before reaching next line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I'm learning Node.js.

I have to call an async function `work()` inside my `Promise.all()` loop and it must be completed before moving on to statements that are after the Promise.all().
Currently, it reaches the `FINISH` statment before completing `work()`.

What is the right way to make the code wait for work() function to complete?

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const promise2 = Promise.resolve(2);
const promise3 = Promise.resolve(3);

async function work() {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'foo');
    })
    console.log('some work here')
}

async function main() {
    await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
        values.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item)
            work()
        });
    });
    console.log('FINISH')
}

main()
```

Comment: Why do call `Promise.all()` with an array of already resolved `Promise`s? That doesn't make much sense...

Comment: All of your 3 promises are already resolved. Don't mix and match `await` and `then`...

Comment: You need to return the promise from `work()` and invoke the following functionality in `then()` - exactly as you are with `promiseN`. That being said, the `promiseN` seem entirely redundant as you already resolve them before you call `Promise.all()`...? I assume this is just a contrived demo example?

Comment: The initial [promise1, promise2, promise3] promise block is just for illustration, I am doing some files download there and the goal is to do some operation on those files once all of them are downloaded.

Comment: _"is just for illustration ... do some operation on those files"_ - Then write that in the question because right now your example doesn't do anything useful (neither the `Promise.all()` nor the `work()` call that ignores the `item`s and therefor your script does the same what `work(); work(); work();` would do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're really after here, but don't mix and match `await` and `then`, in general.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const promise2 = Promise.resolve(2);
const promise3 = Promise.resolve(3);

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function work(value) {
  await delay(1000 * value);
  console.log("some work here", value);
  await delay(1000);
  return value * 2;
}

async function main() {
  // Doesn't really do much, since these are already resolved...
  const values = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
  // Pass all of those values to `work`, which returns a promise,
  // and wait for all of those promises to resolve.
  const workedValues = await Promise.all(values.map(work));
  console.log(workedValues);
}

main();
```

prints out (the first lines with various delays)

```
some work here 1
some work here 2
some work here 3
[ 2, 4, 6 ]
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I understand now I have to use another Promise.all() for the work() to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `await` before calling your `work()` function.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.